# How to tell if a directory is remotely mounted using Java

Tags: java, mount

Is there a way to determine programatically if a particular directory is actually remotely mounted? Can this be done with Java, and if not can it be done with native C code over JNI?

Since this is Java it could be running under Linux or Windows or Mac, so a proper solution needs to address all these platforms. (Again if its multiple separate solutions with C over JNI thats ok). And there may be different cases like with NFS or samba or anything else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

for Linux, and possibly Macintosh, you can use system library through JNI.
The relevant system call is `getmntent`, [described here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent).

There is a field in `mntent` you can use to check to see if mount point is from device or a server, `mnt_fsname`, in a similar field you can get filesystem type, `mnt_type"

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, you can parse /etc/mtab to find the filesystem type (nfs, smb, etc.) and match it against known network filesystem types in your program.

EDIT: column 2 is what you want in /etc/mtab

Answer (score 0):

I need that as well and might end up implementing it using this command:

df -k

That works under Linux, Mac OS and Solaris.

Maybe this is something else that will be added to JDK 7 since they're also going to support symlinks.